# Electromagnetism and electrostatic forces. How are they related and different?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

So I am new to the stuff of electromagnetism, and frequently when talking about electromagnetism, you hear of electrostatic forces as well. What are the differences between the two and how are they connected or related? Are there any tutorials or resources online to learn about these things?

Comment: Maxwell's equations relate magnetism and electric current. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell's_equations

Comment: Much too broad a set of questions?

Answer (score 1):

Electrostatics is the theory built around static charges - as in charges that are not in motion (or at least, not in any rapid motion). Similarly, magnetostatics discusses systems with steady, non-alternating currents. Electrodynamics accounts for more the general case: as the name implies, the charge distributions can be dynamic - in motion.

It's mostly nomenclature. All of this theory falls under classical electromagnetism and can be described via [Maxwell's equations](http://www.maxwells-equations.com/).

For more information, consider the Wiki on [Electromagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetism) and the menu displayed on that page. Also consider the [Hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/emcon.html#emcon) page on the subject, which may be more approachable.

Answer (score 1):

There is electric force, which is force between electric charges. Then there is magnetic force, which is the force between magnetic substances and magnetic fields produced when charges move. When these two forces act on something simultaneously we call the phenomenon ***Electromagnetism***.

For learning physics as a beginner, I strongly suggest the books *Physics for scientists and engineers* or *Fundamentals of physics by Halliday, Resnick and Walker*.

For further clearing of doubts, or can be used instead of those books, you can use [khan academy](http://www.khanacademy.org) but those books especially physics for scientists and engineers just make you fall in love with Physics. So I would strongly recommend buying the book if you can afford it. Khan academy is free by the way.